# Write a function that accepts HTML DOM document element that reads script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So i know when a block of HTML is loaded via AJAX, script tags embedded in it are not automatically run, even if the HTML block is inserted into the document.  I want to write a function that accepts a HTML DOM Document object and runs all the script tags in the document.  It only needs to do embedded scripts.

I believe "innerHTML" is my best bet for getting the source code.  Other than that, I'm lost in how to write this function...

```
function runScripts(doc{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) with third parameter set to `true`

```js
var html = "<div><script>console.log($.now())<\/script></div>";
var res = $.parseHTML(html, document, true)[0].outerHTML;
$("body").append(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

var doc = document;
function getEmbededScriptTags(){
  var scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName('script'), results = [];
  for(var i=0,l=scripts.length; i<l; i++){
    var script = scripts[i];
    if(!script.src){
      results.push(script);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
function logEmbededScriptTagInnerHTML(){
  var scripts = getEmbededScriptTags();
  for(var i=0,l=scripts.length; i<l; i++){
    console.log(scripts[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
logEmbededScriptInnerHTML();

}
//]]>
```

Comment: The real question is why would you want to do this anyways?